# Unable to enable Read Scale-out on Azure SQL

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database

I have a Premium Azure SQL database which I want to enable Read Scale-out for.

I followed the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-read-scale-out

I have tried both the REST API (using resources.azure.com) and the Powershell API

```
Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase -DatabaseName "dbname" -ServerName "server" -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroup" -ReadScale Enabled
```

This takes a few seconds then returns the following:

```
ResourceGroupName             : myresourcegroup
ServerName                    : server
DatabaseName                  : dbname
Location                      : westeurope
DatabaseId                    : <guid>
Edition                       : Premium
CollationName                 : SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
CatalogCollation              :
MaxSizeBytes                  : 536870912000
Status                        : Online
CreationDate                  : 17/11/2016 07:42:26
CurrentServiceObjectiveId     : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
CurrentServiceObjectiveName   : PX
RequestedServiceObjectiveName : PX
RequestedServiceObjectiveId   :
ElasticPoolName               :
EarliestRestoreDate           : 25/10/2018 00:00:00
Tags                          :
ResourceId                    : /subscriptions/mysub/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/server/databases/dbname
CreateMode                    :
ReadScale                     : Disabled
ZoneRedundant                 : False
Capacity                      : XXXX
Family                        :
SkuName                       : Premium
LicenseType                   :
```

I get similar results with the REST API.

I have raised a support ticket with Microsoft but has anyone encountered this before? Am I running the wrong command?

Comment: Not sure but I've found cmdlets to be unreliable and often use the Azure Resource Manager REST API instead. What version of PS are you using? You need Azure PowerShell version 2016 or later.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried the REST API and it gives me a positive response but also doesn't change the value.

I'm using Azure Powershell April 2018.

I am now wondering if it is because the database was originally created in the Standard Tier and scaled up over the course of the last year.

Comment: Please update us if you get any information. That seems inconveniently probable.

Comment: My guess was incorrect - I believe it just takes a little while to enable on a large database such as ours. 

This morning it is all working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked with the engineering team.  The feature is enabled after you do this, but there is currently a bug in the reporting through the cmdlet.  The fix for this is in-process and will be rolled out to the fleet in the next round of code deployments.  Apologies for your bad experience.

Read scale-out should work now, so go add ReadIntent to your connection string and give it a go.

Conor
Architect, SQL

Comment: Thanks for response Conor.

It was enabled when I came to work this morning so I am happy enough.